# Quick questions about pronouns in a sentence

Tags: pronouns, determiners

I'm confused when it comes to writing the following:
"..., I bought from my one of the sweet sweet friends"
vs
"...., I bought from one of my sweet sweet friends"

Neither me or my partner is native in the English language. Could someone elaborate how I should think when it comes to using pronouns in this sort of context? And also are both the above sentences correct?

Comment: Not a native speaker but "one of my sweet sweet friends" sounds much better.

Comment: To avoid making the duplication of "sweet" look like a typographical error, I would recommend writing, "I bought it from one of my sweet, sweet friends." Or, if the first part of the sentence says what you purchased, then you might write, "..., which I bought from one of my sweet, sweet friends." In either case, the extra comma is helpful.

Comment: I think the comma is not just helpful, but required.

Answer (score 1):

In English, words for parts of the body (head, leg, hand) and personal relations (son, parents, sister, boss, colleague) are nearly always qualified by a possessive rather than "the". So "my friends">

Answer (score 0):

one of my sweet sweet friends OR
one of the sweet sweet friends of mine.

one of is to limit only one member of your sweet sweet friends.

Answer (score 0):

***my one of the sweet friends*** is a partitive construction. You wanted to mean one friend from your many sweet friends. But you have constructed the phrase incorrectly.

***one of my sweet friends*** is correct. Here ***one*** is a determinative and it's a ***Fused Determinative Phrase*** in that construction.

A genitive case of a pronoun (i.e *my*) can't be used before a Fused Determinative Phrase.

Therefore ***my one of the sweet friends*** is incorrect grammatically.

Comment: But "one of the sweet friends" is not idiomatic in any English I know, because (as I said in my answer) most relation words (like "friend") nearly always take possessives. The only context in which I would expect to find "one of the [anything] friends" is in a narrative about a group of friends,which doesn't appear to be what this is about. Is "one of the friends" (to mean "one of my friends") idiomatic in Indian English?

Comment: @ColinFine *nods* yes now I see it. It sounds really odd. I will edit my answer.